# database connection with php page in xampp

Tags: xampp

Friends I am using `xampp` software. I have created a database and then a php page. I know how to run the php page by using `xampp` but when I tried to connect php page with the database, I am getting an error.

```
Error(Warning: mysql_connect(): Host 'fe80::e15b:3b0:1257:7afe%13' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\xampp\htdocs\sant\insert.php on line 4
Could not connect: Host 'fe80::e15b:3b0:1257:7afe%13' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server).
```

I am using the hostname as `localhost`, even I tried with my pc name but that is not working. I have referred lot of sites but didn't get the exact answer.
somebody please help me to overcome this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you write code like following

```
 <?php

$host = "localhost"; //your localhost name
$user = "xcode"; //your username
$pass = "xcode"; //your password
$db="xcode";  //your database name

$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$r) {
    echo "Could not connect to server\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
echo "Connection established\n"; 
}

echo mysql_get_server_info() . "\n"; 
$r2 = mysql_select_db($db);

if (!$r2) {
echo "Cannot select database\n";
 trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
echo "database selected\n"; 
}
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

you try this code.

Comment: still Iam getting the following warning:Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'santosh'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sant\amrita.php on line 8
Could not connect to server 
Fatal error: Access denied for user 'santosh'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sant\amrita.php on line 12

Comment: give what password you give to create account in xampp

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database_name');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'connect failed: '.mysqli_connect_errno();
} else {
    echo 'connected !';
}
```

Try this and post the result

Comment: I am getting a blank screen,I dont no why??

Comment: Blank screen? ok try printing a "Hello world" to check if you are on the same script you are coding :P